# In my code I have a cube and it seems to skip along whenever a direction is just tapped

Tags: java, performance

I am writing a code to practice for the AP test and in my code the cube I put will skip a large amount whenever a direction key is tapped but if it's tapped then I want it to not move.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class Cance extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
        Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
        int x = 50, velX = 0, y = 200, velY = 0, x2 = 50, velX2 = 0, y2 = 500, velY2 = 0;
        int copX = 0; int copY = 0; 
    public Cance(){
        tm.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        tm.start();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(copX, copY, 50, 50);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("keyPressed");
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if(copX > x && copY > y){
        copX -= x/100;
        copY -= y/100;
        }
        if(copX > x && copY < y){
        copX -= x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(copX < x && copY > y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY -= y/100;
        }
        if(copX < x && copY < y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(copX == x && copY < y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(copX == x && copY > y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(copX < x && copY == y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(copX > x && copY == y){
        copX += x/100;
        copY += y/100;
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            velX = -1;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            velX = 0;
            velY = -1;
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            velX = 1;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            velX = 0;
            velY = 1;
        }
        int b = e.getKeyCode();

        if(b == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            velX2 = -1;
            velY2 = 0;
        }
        if(b == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            velX2 = 0;
            velY2 = 0;
        }
        if(b == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            velX2 = 1;
            velY2 = 0;
        }
        if(b == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            velX2 = 0;
            velY2 = 0;
        }


        repaint();
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("keyReleased");
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("keyTyped");
    }


}

public class RacesTester {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame wind = new JFrame();
        wind.setBounds(50, 50, 600, 600);
        wind.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wind.setVisible(true);
        wind.setResizable(true);
        wind.add(new Cance());
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to detect a key-tap vs a key-press? How would you specify "how long" to hold a key down to differentiate the two? A tap is a press...

Comment: Actually, that really helped me find a way past it, thank you so much.

Comment: Okay, cool. You're welcome to answer your own question below in case someone else stumbles across this post